# Open Word Document in Browser with Inline Editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> [Can you do complex editing of Word Documents in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726293/can-you-do-complex-editing-of-word-documents-in-a-browser)

Hi All,

Is there any free tool available that allows to open and edit word documents inside browser.
I am using ASP.Net 2008 Express IDE.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you do complex editing of Word Documents in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726293/can-you-do-complex-editing-of-word-documents-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 2):

Solutions to this problem already exist [(Google Docs)](http://docs.google.com). You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726293/can-you-do-complex-editing-of-word-documents-in-a-browser) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Word itself as an Active X object, as long as your users use IE and have Word installed.

It may be as easy as returning the document with the right mime type `application/msword`

Answer (score 0):

Even though it isn't available yet, I would keep an eye on the Office Web Applications.  Here is some initial information:

http://workspace.officelive.com/en-us/Office-Web-Applications