# Editing Documents (.doc) in Browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-office

I've been developing a web application with asp.net webforms and in this app I have some documents (.doc, .docx, .rtf files), and my client want to edit these files on browser, they want to open a document in an editor, edit, save it on server (without downloading) and close it. I know it's difficult but I would like to know if it's possible or if is there any easy way to do it. We find something like SkyDrive of Microsoft.

PS: We can pay for components if you can suggest something that really works.

Thank you!

Comment: check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053042/open-word-document-in-browser-with-inline-editing

Comment: WebDAV is the way to go.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792960/editing-ms-office-documents-from-a-web-application-custom-webdav-implementation

Comment: seems related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081266/ms-word-2010-with-aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*IF the clients have Office installed*:

I would recommend http://www.webdavsystem.com/server - this allows you to build a "virtual filesystem" ([WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) which is based on HTTP) which Office can access thus allowing the client to open/edit/save a document (DOCX etc.) via HTTP(S)... it is pure .NET, integrates nicely with ASP.NET and has even a JavaScript accessible API... esp. the upcoming V 3 comes with a wizard which allows you easily to add that funcionality to your ASP.NET application... (just a happy customer, not affilliated).

*IF the clients don't have Office installed then it gets tricky:*

To really fully support you would need some sort of Silverlight/Flash/ActiveX/JavaApplet which runs in the clients browser and supports the needed editing features...

I am not aware of such production-quality components except the ones from Microsoft - see http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/online-software.aspx

You could integrate them into your web application although they won't offer the full Office feature set in the browser...

Comment: Hi Yahia, Thanks for awser. My clientes have Office installed. I will check this webdav system. I don't want any File Browser in my app. I have some records in database and each record has a .doc or .docx file associated in my server's disc, so I need to open it on Office to my client edit and save on server. Is the WebDAVSystem work like that? Thanks =)

Comment: @FelipeOriani You can make it work like that - this library allows to load/write/edit files from anywhere (for example from a database)...