# ms word 2010 with aspx

Tags: asp.net, windows, ms-word

I want to display a Word 2010 document inside of an aspx page. The user will select some word ranges and the position of this selection will need to  be sent server side.  Conversion, displaying rtf or any other solution will not work because they need the input to be the same as html to display. Is there is any alternate option for my problem?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: that link doesn't really apply.  It is for manipulating office documents server side, not for embedding them in web pages.

Comment: Why is a conversion to HTML not an option?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to display word 2010 inside an aspx page.

That's simply not possible.

If conversion of the documents isn't an option, then you need to change over to either using a desktop app in which you can embed word in a regular form OR use webdav in combination with some type of word extension or vbscript embedded in the document itself to handle what you are after.

**update**
see Nancy's response.  Looks like there might be a way after all.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my case converting to html is not a good option because main requirement is they want to display input as same.  In some cases after converting word to HTML alignment will differ.