# Is there a Microsoft Word Component for the Classic ASP?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, ms-word, wysiwyg, spell-checking

Is there a Microsoft Word (or Word-Like) Component for the Web - Specifically, Classic ASP?
Something that can attach to multiple instances of HTML textareas...

The platform is a homegrown, in-house corporate-type app, so it really limits our maneuverability. That said, we just need it to work in plain old web pages using Classic ASP.

Requirements:

1. IE6+ Compatible
2. WYSIWYG
3. Spell Check (offline data dictionary)
4. jQuery (More wish list than requirement)

Please, no why are you using Classic ASP answers! Believe me, if we could use something else, we would...Thanks!

Comment: how do you mean attach to textareas?

Comment: You might want to see this question on http://stackoverflow.com/q/726293/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I cannot post comments.

But does requirement of jQuery imply that processing has to be on client machine?

Anyway, please note [1] that

- **Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment" [1]**

Plz check the enumeration of problems in "Problems using server-side Automation of Office" section of [1]

Just from the coder who coded it - don't do that (it hurts!) through Office components/libraries.  MS Office is not created for non-attended (non-interactive) use.

And it is violation of MS licensing if you cannot assure that all clients have licenses for MS Office. But how can you assure it in web application, if it is not for corporate internal use

[1]
Considerations for server-side Automation of Office
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try [*CKEditor*](http://ckeditor.com/)

> Online text editor (DHTML editor), for
>   ASP, ASP.NET, ColdFusion, PHP, Java
>   and JavaScript brings to the web many
>   of the powerful features of known
>   desktop editors like Word. It's XHTML
>   compliant and works with Firefox,
>   Mozilla, Netscape and IE.

[image]

Comment: That's an old version, the version 3 has been renamed to CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Consider finding a solution involving Google Docs.

Here's an example on how to [Open Any Document in Google Docs Via a Url](http://www.justinball.com/2008/08/28/open-any-document-in-google-docs-via-a-url/)

Perhaps create an `<iframe>`, and have it load [docs.google.com](http://docs.google.com/) with your .doc/.docx

Answer (score 0):

For spellchecking in a web page in IE, just install ieSpell.

Here is another editor:  http://www.fccn.pt/htmlarea/