# Edit word document online in c#.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Can I edit a word file online in a browser as Google doc? Is there any control available in `asp.net` `c#`?

Comment: refer this [link](http://www.lesson8.blogspot.com/2011/12/word-file-create-in-wpf-c.html)

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to do, but the short answer is yes.

[Use google docs in asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566239/use-google-docs-in-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would be better off with [Office Web Apps,](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/web-apps/) than. Refer for similar threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726293/can-you-do-complex-editing-of-word-documents-in-a-browser) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053042/open-word-document-in-browser-with-inline-editing)